# Rails deletes record in Terminal but RSpec still show the record being there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am creating an app that will interact with a front end to post to a db. On my delete endpoint, in the terminal it shows the record as being deleted. But in my test it still shows as there. Here is my test...

```
it 'can delete just one favorite leaving the rest' do
  user   = create(:user)
  vid    = video_payload
  vid_2  = video_payload_2

  post "/api/v1/users/#{user.id}/favorites/#{vid[:id]}", params:video_payload
  post "/api/v1/users/#{user.id}/favorites/#{vid_2[:id]}", params:video_payload_2

  expect(user.favorites.length).to eq(2)
  expect(user.favorites[1].video_id).to eq(vid_2[:id].to_i)

  delete "/api/v1/users/#{user.id}/favorites/#{vid[:id]}"

  expect(user.favorites.length).to eq(1)
  expect(user.favorites[0].video_id).to eq(vid_2[:id].to_i)
end
```

The expectations after the delete are the ones failing.

```
def destroy
    # user = User.find(params[:id])
    # favorite = Favorite.find_by(user_id: params[:id], video_id: params[:video_id])
    # render json: Favorite.delete(favorite.id)
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    favorite = Favorite.find_by(user_id: params[:id], video_id: params[:video_id])
    user.favorites.delete(favorite) if favorite
  end
```

I have tried these two ways to delete the record(the commented out and the uncommented)

Favorite is a joins between Users and another table. It's a many to many relationship. I have tried it with the dependent destroy on other table and users and without still same error.

Comment: Have you tried reloading the user object in your spec just to be sure? You can try something like `user.reload.favorites.length`.

Comment: @DerekHopper That did the trick! Thank you. If you submit the answer I can accept it so you get the credit :D I've done that in the terminal, but didn't realize it could be done in the test. I'm going to go read up on that now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your spec, you have this:

```
expect(user.favorites.length).to eq(1)
```

Try this instead. Reload the user object before you check the length of favorites.

```
expect(user.reload.favorites.length).to eq(1)
```

Rails uses a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` to keep track of the association. When you fetch it the first time, it caches the results. `reload` will make sure you get fresh results.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html